# AngularJS filter to show another value from DB based on value in iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm converting a pure Laravel (and jQuery) application to Angular/Laravel.

I have this snippet:

```
<td>{{ Person::byId($record->id) }}</td>
```

In my iteration I called a function to get a name based on the id in the iteration.  I know I need to use a filter to do this in Angular.

If I have an API endpoint set up to receive the ID and respond with the name, how can I set up my table below to work with that filter?

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
    <td>{{record.id | filter to show name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Just to be sure you want to fetch data and then filter it by ID or fetch filtered data by ID?

Comment: I want to show the name based on the id in the iteration, which can be taken from the API endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this all without Angular although it's tagged as an Angular question.  It could have been done on the server-side or on the client-side, but I did it on the server-side because it was much easier to do so.

Here's my Laravel query:

`$records = DB::table('records')->get();`

After getting this `stdClass array`, I iterated over it and had an external static method to return the name of based on the id.

Example:

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    $record->id = Person::byId($record->id);
}
```

I then responded with JSON in my API endpoint with the above, modified data.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).filter('name', function() {
  return function(input) {
     //function/call a service to get the name based on record.id which is the input
     return name;
  };
});
```

Then on your view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
    <td>{{record.id | name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Beware though, if you have a couple of records on your db, it might get overwhelmed with the looped requests.

Comment: It crashed my db.  What's an alternative?

Comment: Another way is to create a service that retrieves your records with the name on it.

Comment: And then combine the two arrays (names and records) and only send that?

Comment: That's one way. Or restructure your query to return both names and records in one result, if it isn't so hard.